# Share underscore mixins across node.js modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js, npm

I'd like to share an underscore mixin from a mode submodule with its parent module. Here's my setup:

```
.
├── index.js
└── node_modules
    └── submodule
        ├── index.js
        ├── node_modules
        │   └── underscore
        │       ├── LICENSE
        │       ├── README.md
        │       ├── package.json
        │       ├── underscore-min.js
        │       └── underscore.js
        └── package.json
```

**./index.js:**

```
var submodule = require('submodule')
  , _ = require('underscore');

console.log('In main module : %s', _.capitalize('hello'));
```

**./node_modules/submodule/index.js:**

```
var _ = require('underscore');

_.mixin({
  capitalize : function(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.substring(1).toLowerCase();
  }
});

console.log('In submodule : %s', _.capitalize('hello'));
```

When i run `node index.js` I get the following output:

```
In submodule : Hello

/Users/lxe/devel/underscore-test/index.js:4
console.log('In main module : %s', _.capitalize('hello'));
                                     ^
TypeError: Object function (obj) {
    if (obj instanceof _) return obj;
    if (!(this instanceof _)) return new _(obj);
    this._wrapped = obj;
  } has no method 'capitalize'
```

As you can see, the mixin was registered in submodule (`In submodule : Hello`). However, `_.capitalize` is undefined in the main module.

How can I make the modules share the mixins?

Comment: The problem is that `submodule` has it's own underscore. You can access it from main module using `require('submodule/node_modules/underscore')`. NPM version control model even allows `submodule` to have different version of underscore installed, for example, it may be some custom build from git.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny thank you. `submodule/node_modules/underscore` is the only place I have underscore. I thought that if require grabs it from the same location, it becomes cached throughout the process. Is it possible to do this without having to do require('submodule/node_modules/underscore') every time?

Comment: The fact that `require('underscore')` works in main module means that you **do have** another underscore installed. It's possible for submodule to access its parents submodules through `require` as its own dependency, but not the contrary.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny You are correct. I looked at `require.cache` and there was indeed another underscore. I was under the assumption require traverses the node_modules tree to find the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out! I needed to change my tree a bit:

```
├── index.js
└── node_modules
    ├── submodule
    │   ├── index.js
    │   └── package.json
    └── underscore
        ├── LICENSE
        ├── README.md
        ├── package.json
        ├── underscore-min.js
        └── underscore.js
```

Now only the root module has the 'underscore' module. I'm guessing doing require('underscore') in the submodule either uses a cache of the require from the main module, or traverses the tree upwards to find it.

Comment: Actually, it looks for the local `underscore` first. If there is no local `underscore` then it uses its parent's `underscore`.

Comment: The only thing I don't like in this solution is that you'll need to remove `underscore` from `submodule`'s `package.json`.